# Add a fee in WooCommerce for a specific product category, but only when related categories also present

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, fee

I want to add a fee for a category (A), but to be calculated only when in the order are products from other categories (B, C, D, etc).

But if only category A products are ordered, that tax does not apply.

In my code the fee is added in both situations. Can you guide me for a better solution?

I add this code on my site:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_pcat_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_pcat_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Set HERE your categories (can be term IDs, slugs or names) in a coma separated array
    $categories = array('396');
    $fee_amount = 0;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) )
            $fee_amount = 20;
    }

    // Adding the fee
    if ( $fee_amount > 0 ){
        // Last argument is related to enable tax (true or false)
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __( "Taxa livrare ROPET", "woocommerce" ), $fee_amount, false );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_post_terms()` to retrieves the terms for a post. When going through the cart contents we collect the term ids,
which we can then compare to see if there is a match.

WordPress functions used:

- [wp_get_post_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) - Retrieves the terms for a post

PHP functions used:

- [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - Checks if a value exists in an array
- [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) - Computes the intersection of arrays

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // Only use term IDs
    $category_a = 15;
    $other_categories = array( 16, 17, 18 );
    
    // Fee amount
    $fee_amount = 20;
    
    // Initialize
    $term_ids = array();
    
    // Loop through cart contents
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {      
        // Get product id
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        
        // Retrieves the terms for a post.
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        
        // Loop through
        foreach ( $terms as $term_id ) {
            // Checks if a value NOT exists in an array
            if ( ! in_array( $term_id, $term_ids ) ) {
                // Push
                $term_ids[] = $term_id;
            }   
        }
    }
    
    // Check for a specific category (A)
    if ( in_array( $category_a, $term_ids ) ) {
        // Check if ANY of the term ids exist
        if ( ! empty ( array_intersect( $other_categories, $term_ids ) ) ) {            
            // Last argument is related to enable tax (true or false)
            $cart->add_fee( __( 'Taxa livrare ROPET', 'woocommerce' ), $fee_amount, false );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but I couldn't get what I want. so I would like that when products from category A (only products of category A) are in the cart the fee to not be added. but when in the basket are added products from other categories the fee to be added. thank you!

Comment: @DobosDaniel In your question you state: _"I want to add a fee for a category (A), but to be calculated only when in the order are products from other categories (B, C, D, etc)."_ - 
that's exactly what my answer does, now you seem to be describing/asking another question. However, it is not the intention to change your question on Stack Overflow afterwards so that I have to change my answer again...